# Compare words and return Pandas DataFrame entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I am planning to set up a simple function to see if words from a wordlist can be found in a Pandas DataFrame `common_words`. In case of a match, I would like to return the corresponding DataFrame entry, while the DF has the format `life balance 14`, `long term 9`, `upper management 9`, highlighting the word token and its occurrence number.

The code below is however currently only printing the search term from the wordlist (i.e. `life balance`), not the DataFrame entry that includes the occurrence count. I would hence need to find a way to return `word` instead of the `wordlist` element. Where is my error in reasoning?

The relevant code section is:

```
    # Check for matches between wordlist and Pandas dataframe
    def wordcheck():
        wordlist = ["work balance", "good management", "work life"]
        for x in wordlist:
            if df[i].str.contains(x).any():
                print('Group 1:', x)
    wordcheck()
```

The full code segment looks as follows:

```
# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)


# Datetime conversion
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Adding of 'Quarter' column
df['Quarter'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('Q')


# Word frequency analysis
def get_top_n_bigram(corpus, n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]


# Analysis loops through different qualitative sections
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram(df[i], 500)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(word, freq)


    # Check for matches between wordlist and Pandas dataframe
    def wordcheck():
        wordlist = ["work balance", "good management", "work life"]
        for x in wordlist:
            if df[i].str.contains(x).any():
                print('Group 1:', x)
    wordcheck()
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but is this because you are only printing the searched term?
So would something similar to the below work better?

```
# Check for matches between wordlist and Pandas dataframe
def wordcheck():
    wordlist = ["work balance", "good management", "work life"]
    for x in wordlist:
        print('Group 1:', df[i][df[i].str.contains(x).any()])
wordcheck()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, it currently returns the searched term. I have tried the code you suggested, which however led to `print('Group 1:', df[i][df[i].str.contains(x).any()]), KeyError: True`

Comment: You would presumably have to add your column name, so `print('Group 1:', df[i][df[i]['column_name'].str.contains(x).any()])`

Comment: Good idea, it's returning true for the values, but not the `word` variable. I think it will directly have to be linked to `word` as only this variable connects the word token and the number of occurrences.

Comment: So maybe best would be something like:   `print('Group 1:', df[i].loc[df[i]['column_name'].str.contains(x).any()])` ?

Comment: Thanks anyways for your efforts